# How would an efficient OAuth2.0 server / provider work?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, oauth-2.0, digital-signature

I may need to implement an OAuth2.0 server for an API I'm creating. This API would allow 3rd parties to perform actions on the user's behalf.

OAuth2.0 has 3 mains calls. First, there is a call to prompt the user for consent. This returns a `code`. The second is where the `code` is exchanged for a `access token`. Finally, the `access token` is used to call the API on the user's behalf.

For implementation, I was thinking the first call generates a random string which acts as a `code`. The `code` is then stored in a database with a pointer to the current User and a random `HMAC Key`, then the random data is returned to the 3rd party as the `code`.

When the 3rd party requests an `access token`, another piece of random data is generated and concatenated with the `code`. This string is signed using the `HMAC key` from Step 1, then this signed string and signature is returned with the signature to form the `access token`.

When the API call occurs, the `hmac key` corresponding to the provided `access_token` is retrieved from the database. The signature of the `access_token` is verified using the hmac key.

The user can revoke 3rd party access by simply removing an HMAC key from their list of authorized HMAC keys. Furthermore, but just signing random data, I can avoid storing every single access_token every created, and instead maintain a short list of hmac keys.

Anyway, this is my first attempt as thinking through this. Surprisingly, there is little information about implementing the server side of OAuth2.0 efficiently. I would prefer to keep as little information as possible in the database. The advantage of signing random data then later revoking the HMAC key is that I don't have to store every single `access token` generated by every single authorization call.

Thoughts needed! There has got to be a better way!

EDIT:

I'm NOT looking for an implementation. Thank you though! Also, I assume this whole system will run over HTTPs. Also, I'm talking about the pure OAuth2.0 flow, I'm *not* talking about OAuth1.0 with signatures and client keys. I'm asking how to design the cryptography behind an OAuth2.0 server that would work in a similar fashion to (for example) Google's OAuth2.0 flow works.

Comment: Do you really need to store so many access tokens? or just re-issue the same ones per user?  You mention you don't want to store so much info in database - do you have the option of in memory/memcached storage that may make sense?

Comment: Yes, there would be a lot of access tokens, as they are re-issued often. Consequently, I'm not looking for database solutions, I'm looking for cryptographic solution that can be merely storing a few keys for each user, rather than millions of access tokens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have an exact answer to this, but let's try to put the pieces together - 
i) I am not too sure if you need to save the authorization code in your database for long. This is what Facebook says -

> New security restrictions for OAuth authorization codes 
>   We will only allow authorization codes to be exchanged for access tokens once and will require that they be exchanged for an access
>   token within 10 minutes of their creation. This is in line with the
>   OAuth 2.0 Spec which from the start has stated that "authorization
>   codes MUST be short lived and single use". For more information, check
>   out our Authentication documentation.

See this link, https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/ (December 5, changes).

ii) What about doing what you are doing till step 1, keep the authorization code and HMAC key in the DB. ***Let's have the authorization code for 10 mins (or whatever you feel is necessary) and then remove the authorization code.***

iii) Let's say you have a single sign-in service that authenticates a client's credentials. When the client app hits the token exchange endpoint (auth code for access token) you'd need to fetch the HMAC key and return the access token. **Why not add (some random data + timestamp + customerID/customer name(or something that can be used to uniquely identify the user)) and sign it with the key and return all this data as the access token.**

 You can think about using a new HMAC key perhaps and replacing the old one.

iv) When the client hits any API endpoint with the token, let the srvice internally call **a CustomerIDExtractorService that fetches the HMAC key from the DB and decrypts the access token and returns the customerID to the relevant API**. The independent process can then use to the customer ID to fetch data. So basically, I ask you to separate the login/token generation/token info extraction process to a separate unit.

**Let's try to map this to how Google could be doing something like this**

i) You use an app and sign in to Google Oauth. (Let a black box X from google handle the login).
ii) Your app hits the token exchange endpoint -> The service internally checks if the code is valid. If it is, the service combines some data + customerID and signs it and returns it to the app as an access token.
iii) The app now hits (say) the google+ endpoint. Internally, the service transfers the token to black box X, which decrypts the token and returns customer ID to G+ service. g+ then maps the C_ID to relevant customer data.

**Another suggestion**
Depending on the scope that the app requested, you can add more info to the access token. Maybe create a JSON object and add/remove fields according to the scope selected by the app. Sign the JSON string as the access token.

Comment: Well thought out answer, several points I need to think about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your description started off OK, but then I must confess I could only partly follow your approach.  AFAIK OAuth2 relies heavily on HTTPS rather than signed requests, although I guess you're free to use such.

I'm not sure about the concept you present to revoke access.  Typically this would rely just on the access token (it should expire at some point in time, you could revoke it, and it could be renewed).  If for API requests you are pulling keys for a userid then possibly your code is too closely tied to "user" concepts and not OAuth clients (with role, scope, resources)

In any case it's not a simple standard and I guess the discussion could go on quite long and even then I am not sure all could be covered.  I trust you've reviewed the RFC at:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

I see also from your profile you're likely a Java developer.  In such case it may be a good idea to review Spring-security-oauth2 at:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth

If your solution won't use Java a lot of the issues you allude to in your question were approached and solved by such project, so it should give you lots of ideas.  If you will use Java then it may help you a lot.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Mark thank you at your attempt, but if you read the text explaining how the bounty would be awarded, I wanted an answer based on manipulation of cryptographic primitives.

Comment: No worries. I just gave a general answer because it sounded like the HMAC keys concept was just another (albeit cryto) way of storing something like a revoke-able access token.

Answer (score 0):

Actually most of implementations are using bearer token over https not mac in OAuth 2.0, check [this presentation pages 54-56](http://www.slideshare.net/aaronpk/an-introduction-to-oauth2) about why prefer bearer ,on other hand spring implementation is not supporting MAC token for OAuth 2.0 and there is an open issue about it but [it is still open](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SECOAUTH-50)

for time-being if you are looking for spring implementation demo you can check this [source code](https://github.com/bassemZohdy/Spring_REST_OAuth_Demo) but it is using data base to store tokens, and there is connection have to be done between the resource server and Authorization server, in this demo using data base.

one of open source implementation of Spring OAuth 2.0 is [UAA of cloudfoundry](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) I attend one session about it also they were telling that there is communication have to be done between both servers. [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uBcpsIEz2I)

Comment: The question is, what do to contents of the bearer token mean to the oauth system? Can you answer that?