# How to design oauth 2.0 access token field in Sql?

Tags: sql, database, optimization, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am designing the database for my own OAuth service. My current solution is to have an 512-bit long access token and save it as binary data in sql. Is this a good practice? Do I need varchar type instead? I am worried about the search time to retrieve the row containing the access token. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am missing something, I'll edit right away.

However you are storing the access tokens you **never** need to run a query on the tokens themselves. You would run a query on the userID or something and fetch the access token for that customer. I say this because the tokens are supposed to contain data that you can extract.

**How are you dealing with access tokens?** 
Do read this question - [How would an efficient OAuth2.0 server / provider work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200528/how-would-an-efficient-oauth2-0-server-provider-work)

It discusses how access tokens behave.