# Oauth2: Building Authentication Server and Resource Server

Tags: oauth, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-4

I'm trying to build web services with OAuth2 as Authentication mechanism. Currently I'm trying with Laravel4, and considering bshaffer/oauth2-server-php as OAuth2 provider.

So the current plan is, auth server and resource server is separated. The user sign in to auth server with the GrantType of "Resource Owner Password Credentials", get access token back, and use that to access resources in resource server.

Question is, how should I use access token to access resources on another server? Should I just pass the access token to the resource server when it is issued, and compare it in the resource server when the user sends his along with the resource call?

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200528/how-would-an-efficient-oauth2-0-server-provider-work

Answer (score 0):

Here a complete demo OAuth2 with Laravel 4

https://github.com/raulduran/demo-l4-oauth