# OAuth access token and refresh token creation

Tags: http, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing my own OAuth authentication system (with refresh_token support) for an app and I have some questions about how to do it:

1. Client identification: The client is registered in the auth server and gets a **client_id** and a **client_secret**. How do I generate it? is there some kind of relation between both values?.
2. User authentication: The client sends the **users_credentials** (username+password for example) + **client_id** and gets a **refresh_token** and **(temp?)access_token**. That access_token is the one I should use in further request or I should use a **accesss_token`**=F(refresh_token,access_token,client_secret). In the second case what does the F function consist on?
3. Access token refresh: The client send **client_id**, **refresh_token** and gets a **access_token** (and a optional new refresh_token). Does the **access_token** need the same conversion (whatever it be), as in the point 2?

If I'm wrong, when and how is the client_secret used?
Complete answers and concrete examples will be "bountied".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The authorisation/authentication server generates these values when you create an account with them (for instance when you create a developer account with Facebook or Google). If you are doing these parts yourself, they should be cryptographically secure pseudo-random numbers or letters. Remember that the client ID is usually publically visible, so choose a reasonably large set of alpha-numerics (I use 30 characters). The secret is private and can be harder to guess so I chose 30 digits with letters, numbers and symbols. These are not related to each other, it is just that one is public and the other isn't.
2. The usual way this works is that there is a browser redirect to the auth server passing the client id in the URL (and redirect uri) and specifically NOT the user id and password. The whole point of OAuth2 is that the client system never sees the user name and password, only the auth server. After this redirect, the auth server verifies the client id, checks the username/password (for instance) and then returns to the redirect uri with a temporary code. This temporary code is passed back to the Auth server in order to obtain an access token. Since this call is made as a POST from the server, it also passes the client secret to verify that it really is the correct client system and not someone who stole the client id from somewhere else. At this point, the auth server will return an access token (and optional refresh token - you do not need to use them, I don't).
3. If the client system wants to log the user in without them having to type in their username and password all the time, it can use a refresh token, if available, to call back onto the Auth server and if the Auth server is happy that the refresh token is still valid and any other business rules are correct, it can give you back another access token directly without the user being involved.

I recommend reading the OAuth2 spec here: [OAuth2 Spec RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). It can take a while but if you delete the bits you don't need and reduce the amount of data, there are plenty of useful examples in it.

Answer (score 0):

**FIRSTLY**, The **[client identifier](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-2.2)** can be any string that you want, but it should be unique for each client. It can even be the client's choice if you wish.
The **client secret** should be a cryptographically strong random string. Here is how you could generate one in C#:

```
RandomNumberGenerator cryptoRandomDataGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
cryptoRandomDataGenerator.GetBytes(buffer);
string uniq = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
return uniq;
```

**SECONDLY**, The whole point of OAuth is to allow external apps to do things on your behalf without asking for your credentials. So, you need to implement an authentication server that does the logging in part for you. The user opens the app and gets an option to **Log in using *your website***. You tend out access tokens and refresh tokens once the user has keyed in his credentials. The app can then simply use the tokens to perform actions on the user's behalf. I wrote an answer to [How would an efficient OAuth2.0 server / provider work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200528/how-would-an-efficient-oauth2-0-server-provider-work) that explains how access tokens can be constructed.

Remember, the need for refresh tokens and the lifetime of access tokens purely depends on how you intend to use them and what does your security framework look like.

**LASTLY**, The refresh token can also be an HMAC encoded string/a JSON object as I had explained in the answer to the linked question. You can have random refresh tokens and a large backend storage to keep it to verify the tokens in the incoming requests, or have HMAC encoded strings for added security/less storage requirements/latency to decrypt/encrypt tokens.

Also, do make sure that you go through all the flows and possibly the RFC too as mentioned by Lukos.